# How to add data that doesn't exist on one list to another?

Tags: openrefine

I have two sheets with thousands of records. There are overlaps between the two, in that each record on the two docs use identifiers. I need to migrate the records of what doesn't already exist into the other doc. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible, but if you are familiar with scripting languages like Python or R I currently would recommend using them to perform the merge.

Nevertheless here is a rudimentary recipe to perform the merge using only OpenRefine.

> Note that this behavior might change in the future, watch [GitHub Issue #556](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/556) for that.

Assuming you have two projects called A and B and want to merge into Project B every row from Project A that is not already there yet. The two projects share a common id column.

#### 1. Prepare Project B for synchronization

In Project A mark the rows that are already in Project B using [cross](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#crosscell-s-projectname-optional-s-columnname-optional).
For that [add a new column](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) named "Sync" in Project A based on your ID column using the following GREL expression:

```js
if(
    cell.cross("Project B", "ID column").cells["ID column"].value.length() > 0,
    "Found",
    row.index
)
```

This will use the index of the row as temporary id for synchronization, but only for rows that are not already in Project B.

#### 2. Prepare Project B for synchronization

In Project B we also [add a new column](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) named "Sync" using the following GREL expression:

```js
with(6000, rowsInProjectA,
  with(7000, rowsInProjectB,
    if(row.index + 1 == rowsInProjectB,
      "," + forRange(0, rowsInProjectA, 1, v, v).join(","),
      ""
    )
  )
)
```

This will add a string `,0,1,2,...,6000` in the last row of column "Sync" in Project B. Note that you manually have to determine and set the two variables `rowsInProjectA` (currently 6000) and `rowsInProjectB` (currently 7000).

Then we use [Split multi-valued cells](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#split-multi-valued-cells) on column "Sync" in Project B using the comma `,` as separator. This will basically add new rows to Project B containing only a value in the column "Sync" to be able to load the missing rows from Project A.

#### 3. Load rows from Project A

In Project B we use [cross](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#crosscell-s-projectname-optional-s-columnname-optional) again to to load the missing rows from Project A. For that we use the transformation dialog in the ALL column to be able to load several columns in one step.

```js
if(isNonBlank(row.cells["Sync"].value),
  row.cells["Sync"].cross("Project A", "Sync").cells[columnName].value[0],
  value
)
```

This GREL expression is assuming that the columns in Project A and Project B have the same names. Otherwise you would have to use the [transform](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#transform) dialog on each column separately and manually map the column names from Project A and Project B.

#### 4. Clean up

1. Delete rows in Project B that only contain a value in "Sync" but in no other column (these are rows that already are in Project B and therefore have not been loaded in step 3).
2. Delete column "Sync" in Project B
3. Delete column "Sync" in Project A

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused about how to edit the expression in Step 2. What am I changing? Is "rowsInProjectA" the name of Project A? What should 6000 and 7000 be changed to exactly?

Comment: `rowsInProjectA` and `rowsInProjectB` a variables and should be set to the number of rows that you have in "Project A" and "Project B". Meaning you have to change the number 6.000 to whatever number of total rows you have in "Project A" and the number 7.000 to whatever total number of rows you have in "Project B".

Comment: Let's say A = 10087 and B = 14504, is this right? I'm getting a parsing error saying expects three arguments

`with(10087,
  with(14504,
    if(row.index + 1 == 14504,
      "," + forRange(0, 10087, 1, v, v).join(","),
      ""
    )
  )
)`

Comment: You deleted the variable name from the GREL expression. You need only to replace the numbers.
`with(10087, rowsInProjectA, with(14504, rowsInProjectB, if(row.index + 1 == rowsInProjectB, "," + forRange(0, rowsInProjectA, 1, v, v).join(","), "")))`

Comment: I'm now getting "Parsing error at offset 307: with expects second argument to be a variable name"

`with(10087, rowsInNAMEOFPROJECT-A,
  with(14504, rowsInNAMEOFPROJECT-B,
    if(row.index + 1 == rowsInNAMEOFPROJECT-B,
      "," + forRange(0, rowsInNAMEOFPROJECT-A, 1, v, v).join(","),
      ""
  )
 )
)`

Comment: You do not have to modify the variable name, only the value (number). The problem with your code is, that GREL does not support a hyphen `-` in variable names.

Comment: thanks again for all the help. I got to Step 3 but results led to "text transform on 0 cells" -- any way you possibly know what I did wrong?

Comment: In this context the message says, that it could not find any rows to load. I would suggest you systematically check where it went wrong. Does `row.cells["Sync"].value` give an error in the preview windows, or show results? Does `row.cells["Sync"].cross("Project A", "Sync")` give an error or result?